# Can't open PDF with content resolver

Tags: android, android-contentresolver

I have a PDF that I download to this folder:

```
/data/user/0/com.android.providers.downloads/cache/report-1.pdf
```

It shows in my URI as:

```
content://downloads/all_downloads
```

When I swipe down the notification area, I can open the file, but when I write code to open it, I get an error saying it cannot be open.
I have this permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I open it with:

```
    val intent = Intent()
    intent.action = Intent.ACTION_VIEW

    val fullPath = FileUtils.getPath(context, uri)
    println("Path to file: $fullPath")
    val newUri = Uri.parse(fullPath)
    intent.setDataAndType(newUri, MIME_TYPE_PDF)

    context.startActivity(intent)
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?
Do I need to somehow open it with a stream? I don't want to move the file to SD card, but will if its the only option.

Thanks.

Comment: What Android Version?, as Android 10 has made paths outside of the App's private directories worthless

Comment: Multiple versions. It's not confined to one version. It happens on both physical devices and emulators. I think its my code, rather than an OS issue.